# why are the rows of a unitary matrix orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove that the set of rows of a unitary matrix is orthonormal. I cannot do that although I tried so much. How can I prove this?

Comment: I'm curious what you have "tried so much". All it requires is writing the definition of unitary.

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of an unitary matrix? It would also be good to tell us what you have tried instead that you just tried something.

Answer (score 2):

You know that the row are formed with $f\left(e_i\right)$ where $(e_i)_{i \in [ 1,n ]}$ is the basis in which the matrix is written. You know that $f$ is orthogonal then
$$
\langle f\left(e_i\right),f\left(e_j\right) \rangle=\langle e_i, e_j\rangle
$$

You can try to prove your assessment using this property.